# Warning on case statement

Tags: swift, warnings

Here is a simple example that exhibits the warning:

```
func cvt(value:AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    let test:AnyObject? = nil
    switch value {
    case var (v) where v is String:
        test = v
    default:
        test = value
    }
    return test
}
cvt("xyzzy")
```

The `case` line generates this warning:
`Constant 'v' inferred to have type 'AnyObject?', which may be unexpected`

In a larger context with more `cases` the code does appear to work correctly just with more warnings.

The question: How to eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was described in the latest [**Swift Blog post**](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=13), you need to use **`as`** downcast operator:

```
switch value {
    case let value as String:
        // value is a string
    case let value as Double:
        // value is a double
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had not seen the latest Swift Blog post.